# iOS: Storing Link to UIImageViews in Array, using them afterwards

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I would like to make a UIScrollView which is "page-able" and contains several kind of objects, including images, which are zoomable. So I set up the main UIScrollView and added on those pages with the images additional UIScrollViews which are zoomable and contain as subviews the UIImages. While doing this i store a link to the UIImageViews in an Array:

```
UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:ScrollViewImageRect];
[imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
[imageScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];
imageScrollView.delegate = self;

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
[imagelinkArray addObject:imageView];
[imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];

[self.scrollView addSubview:imageScrollView];
```

In `viewForZoomingInScrollView` i can then just get the current page of the main ScrollView and return the Link:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return [imagelinkArray objectAtIndex:page - 1];
}
```

Works everything fine so far, but now I also would like to reset the zoom scale whenever I swipe to another page, else when I swipe back the Image will be still zoomed-in.

Therefore I'm checking in `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:` if the current page did change which also works fine, but then I don't know how I can actually reset the zoom scale of the UIImageView which is not declared in the .h file and where the only link I have is the one in the Array. How can I change properties of objects where I have this kind of link?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in the meantime I found an answer for my question:

```
UIScrollView *changeScrollView = (UIScrollView*)[imagescrolllinkArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"%@", changeScrollView);
```

which opens the imageScrollView made and stored in the Array before in order to change it's values...